# Health App under ios 8.3

Tags: ios, health.app

I just updated to ios 8.3 on an iPhone5S. I notice that since the upgrade I no longer see the minimum and maximum number of steps or distance i have walked in the health app. It only shows an upper and lower line, not an exact number. It still reads the average over the period but i want my minimum and maximum back. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, not possible, afaik.

I think they likely made the change to make the scale easier to read, but the side effect is you have less info at hand.